# How to check if a string contains a certain word plus equal sign?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
If NOT "%Str%"=="%Str:location==%" (
    echo "location=" found in in string
) else (
    echo no "location=" found in in string
)
```

This doesn't seem to be working as the equal sign isn't detected, how can I get it to work?

Comment: why is the double equal sign at the end?

Comment: You can't use the equals symbol in string substitution.

Comment: Because @npocmaka, the intention is to determine whether the string content `location=` is contained within the expanded variable value of `%Str%`! The implication is that the string character `=` is being mistaken for the substituation statement character `=`.

Comment: Just use the `find` command, `Echo "%Str%"|%__AppDir__%find.exe /I "location=">NUL&&("location=" found in in string)||Echo no "location=" found in in string`

Comment: The `=` separates search from replace string in sub-string substitution expressions, but you have some options: 1. `find` (as already suggested by Compo); 2. `findstr`; 3. additional sub-string expansion: `:LOOP`, then `if defined Str if "%Str%"=="%Str:*location=%" (goto :SKIP) else set "Str=%Str:*location=%"`, then `if "%Str:~,1%"=="=" (echo "location" found in string) else goto :LOOP`, and then `:SKIP`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my earlier comment, you could just use the `find` command/utility for this task.

```batch-file
Echo "%Str%" | %__AppDir__%find.exe /I "location=" 1>NUL && (
    Echo "location=" found in in string
) || Echo no "location=" found in in string
```